# In Perl, why am I getting "reference found where even-size list expected" when I try to initialize a hash?

Tags: perl, hash

I have a script tha ttake as inputs two files :

- An extraction of 200k lines
- The source file

I have to compare extraction against source : each line of the extraction should be in source. If not, I have to log the line a log file.

Below the script :

```
#!/perl/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
# Open log file
open(LOG, '>', 'log.txt');
# Start log
say LOG '['.localtime().'] Début execution';
# Declare extraction number of line counter
my $i_extraction_counter = 1;
# Define files to be compared (extraction against source)
my ($extraction_file, $source_file) = @ARGV;
# Open extraction file
open my $f_extraction, "<", $extraction_file;
# Store extraction file in a hash
my %h_extraction;
while(defined(my $extr_line = <$f_extraction>)){
    $h_extraction{$extr_line} = $extr_line;
    $i_extraction_counter++;
}
# Declare temp hash and counter
my %h_tmp = {};
my $i_counter = 1;
# Open source file
open my $f_source, "<", $source_file;
# For each source line, compare against extraction hash
while(defined(my $source_line = <$f_source>)){
    # If the current line exists in extration hash, stores it in the temp hash & increase counter
    if(defined($h_extraction{$source_line})){
        $h_tmp{$source_line} = $source_line;
        $i_counter++;
    }
    # TO DO : check in elsif if the line should be stored in log (name + firstname OR contract number)
}
# If not all lines of extraction has been stored in temp hash = some lines of extraction are not in source file
if($i_counter < $i_extraction_counter){
    # Declare a second temp hash (used to log missing lines)
    my %h_missing_lines = %h_extraction;
    # For each line of extraction, check if it exists in the first temp hash. If yes, unset it. Only missing line will remain
    foreach my $s_line (keys(%h_missing_lines)){
        if(defined($h_tmp{$s_line})){
            delete($h_missing_lines{$s_line});
        }
    }
    # For each line of missing lines hash, stores it in log file
    foreach my $s_line (keys(%h_missing_lines)){
        say LOG 'Ligne d\'extraction non présente dans fichier source : '.$s_line;
    }
}
say LOG '['.localtime().'] Fin execution';
```

At the execution, this message shows up : `Reference found where even-sized list expected at script.pl line 22, <$f_extraction> line 200000.`

Comment: This is a good example of a case where `use diagnostics` does a particularly good job of explaining the problem. Try `perl -Mdiagnostics -E'my %h = {}'`.

Comment: @DaveCross: I agree, but `use diagnostics` in the program will spew vast amounts of useless words. Used as `perl -Mdiagnostics` in the same way you might use `perl -d` is essential. Just keep it out of the code.

Comment: Good use for PERL5OPT :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On line 22, we have:

```
my %h_tmp = {};
```

Change that to:

```
my %h_tmp;
```

And you will be fine.

The problem here is - `{}` is used to define an anonymous hash - and return a reference.

So you could do:

```
my $hash_ref = {};
```

And that's effectively what you're doing.

```
my %h_tmp = $hash_ref;
```

Initialising a hash with a single value like this, gives exactly the error you are getting, because a hash expects key value pairs.

You could do:

```
my %h_tmp = ();
```

This would work, but would be redundant - you're creating an empty hash either way.

Comment: That's it !! Thanks :)

Comment: @PierrickFlajoulot: Except that, while your code may *work*, you seem to be scared of white space, indenting, layout, etc.

Comment: "perltidy" is big and clever :)

Comment: @Borodin: The way I use to code in PHP. But you're right, it would be clearer with some spaces